# Python formatting not working on Doom Emacs

Tags: python, formatting, doom

I activated the formatting on save in the `init.el` file uncommenting the following line

```
(format +onsave)  ; automated prettiness
```

But when I save a Python file, I get the following error message:

```
Error (before-save-hook): Error running hook "+format-buffer-h" because: (error You need the "black" command. You may be able to install it via "pip install black".)
```

I installed black with pip, as the message says, but I keep getting the same message.

I set the following settings for the Python black formatter (found it [here](https://gist.github.com/jordangarrison/8720cf98126a1a64890b2f18c1bc69f5)):

```lisp
;; package.el
(package! python-black)
```

```lisp
;; config.el
(use-package! python-black
  :demand t
  :after python
  :config
  (add-hook! 'python-mode-hook #'python-black-on-save-mode)
  ;; Feel free to throw your own personal keybindings here
  (map! :leader :desc "Blacken Buffer" "m b b" #'python-black-buffer)
  (map! :leader :desc "Blacken Region" "m b r" #'python-black-region)
  (map! :leader :desc "Blacken Statement" "m b s" #'python-black-statement)
)
```

I did run `doom sync` after changing the settings, and it installed some packages, but I still get the same error when saving Python files.

I'm using Fedora 34, and installed black for Python 3.9. I also tried to install black for Python 2.7, but it's not supported anymore, so I was guessing that maybe Emacs is expecting black to be installed for Python 2.7, That's only a conjecture because I'm new to Emacs and don't know much about it.

Is there a way to make Python formatting work?

Answer (score 1):

I just activated `python` and `(format +onsave)` only.
You must run `doom/reload` (SPC h r r) after `doom sync`.

Activate virtualenv with `SPC : pyvenv-activate`
Install black with `python -m pip install black`
Close open `Python` buffer and open again.

`SPC b s` to save buffer.
`SPC c f` to format buffer / region.

Run `doom doctor` to diagnose problems.